# Trouble understanding the LM555 schematic for 50% duty cycle oscillator mode

Tags: resistors, integrated-circuit, 555, series

I am working with a [LM555CN](https://www.futurlec.com/Linear/LM555CN.shtml) and I am trying to have it run in astable mode and make a LED blink. In essence I am trying to follow along with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRlSFm519Bo&list=PLowKtXNTBypGqImE405J2565dvjafglHU&index=2) video.

Now, there is a part in the chip instructions where it tells you how to set it up in order to have it run with a 50% duty cycle.

[image]

Here is the part where I am not understanding correctly and I would like someone to explain this to me.

[image]

The way I read this (which is wrong apparently) is that these 2 resistors are connected in series (effectively creating a voltage divider, right? Not right?) where the end of the second resistor goes to pin 7 and the half-way point goes to pin 6 (and 2).

In the image attached below, the bottom pair is how I implemented it. The top pair is how it's implemented in the video.

I perceive my implementation as what I see in the schematic, yet it does not work as expected. The LED does not blink and stays on (or it blinks very fast, not sure).

If I make the connections as shown in the video (top pair), it works as expected.

This is where I cannot really wrap my head around how things work with the way they are connected in the video.

The way I see it, the resistors are connected in series again, but this time the half-way point feeds to pin 7 and the end of the 2nd resistor feeds to pin 6, which is not what I see in the schematic.

[image]

Comment: The groups of 6 holes are connected together horizontally as you are looking at them, so in the lower photo pins 6 and 7 are connected together and the resistor is shorted out.

Comment: @Finbarr hm, so after the 1st resistor, the current completely bypasses the 2nd resistor (and pin 7) since it can pass through the red wire jumper?

Comment: It bypasses the resistor because its ends are connected together.

Comment: Oh! I think I get it. So, it's like I have created something like [this](https://img.wallpapersafari.com/desktop/1280/1024/59/89/YQnWev.jpg)?

Comment: @Finbarr Feel free to write an answer if you want the points. I now understand my error, thanks

Comment: ...actually, I am still not sure how should I read that part from the schematic that I pointed out in the question, so please include that as well in your answer. Thanks.